# Error "object is not a function" with array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and AJAX, but I'm trying to take an AJAX's requests' response text and split it into an array (the response text is comma separated). Here's the error I get:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function localhost:36
myrequest.onreadystatechange`

Here's my code:

```
var currentpicid;
var currentcat;
var currentindex;
myrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (myrequest.readyState==4 && myrequest.status==200){ //request successful
        var infoarray = myrequest.responseText.split(',');
        currentpicid = infoarray(0);
        currentcat = "top";
        currentindex = index;

        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=myrequest.responseText;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? I have verified that my PHP page is just outputting a comma separated list of values. Thanks!

Comment: Getting this same error in ES6 for:
`Array.prototype.filter(allChats, chat => chat['response'] != '')`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

```
currentpicid = infoarray(0);
```

you need:

```
currentpicid = infoarray[0];
```

The parentheses are for function calls. Use square brackets for array indexes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew this from PHP but I guess I just overlooked it. Much appreciated, answer will be accepted ASAP.